# How to make/configure an MPI project to run on multiple processes?

Tags: c, eclipse, multiprocessing, mpi

I have a small piece of code that should run on multilple processes, which is :

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include "mpi.h"

  main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
  int ierr, num_procs, my_id;

  ierr = MPI_Init(&amp;argc, &amp;argv);

  /* find out MY process ID, and how many processes were started. */

  ierr = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &amp;my_id);
  ierr = MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &amp;num_procs);

  printf("Hello world! I'm process %i out of %i processes\n",
     my_id, num_procs);

  ierr = MPI_Finalize();
  }
```

the output is :
      Hello world! I'm process 0 out of 1 processes. although it should run on more than one process

We edited the run configurations arguments to "-np 2" so it would run on 2 processes but it always gives us 1 process no matter what the value is.

The used environment is:
Eclipse Juno on Ubuntu 12.04

Source of code: http://condor.cc.ku.edu/~grobe/docs/intro-MPI-C.shtml[^]

Comment: Can you paste the complete shell command that you use to launch your program?

Comment: I don't use commands to run the application, I just run it from the run button on Eclipse

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are trying to launch your MPI application directly, i.e. starting the compiled executable with `-np 2`, like this:

```
$ ./my_app -np 2
```

That's not the right way of launching MPI programs. Instead, you should call your MPI implementation's launcher (usually named `mpirun` or `mpiexec`), and  pass the name of your executable and `-np 2` to that. So if your executable is called `my_app`, then instead of the above command, you should run:

```
$ mpirun -np 2 ./my_app
```

Consult your MPI implementation's documentation for the specifics.

Comment: main@C4C:~/Junoworkspace/testmillion$ mpirun -np 4 testmillion
[proxy:0:0@C4C] HYDU_create_process (./utils/launch/launch.c:69): execvp error on file testmillion (No such file or directory)
[proxy:0:0@C4C] HYDU_create_process (./utils/launch/launch.c:69): execvp error on file testmillion (No such file or directory)
[proxy:0:0@C4C] HYDU_create_process (./utils/launch/launch.c:69): execvp error on file testmillion (No such file or directory)
[proxy:0:0@C4C] HYDU_create_process (./utils/launch/launch.c:69): execvp error on file testmillion (No such file or directory)

Comment: Or did you mean another console on eclipse?

Comment: @dano: That terminal command is correct, it's just that the system couldn't find your executable. You can replace `testmillion` with a path (e.g. `./bin/testmillion`), or change the working directory to where `testmillion` is. Note by the way that the "No such file or directory" error was printed 4 times, so congrats on spawning 4 instances of your app. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. The working directory is where testmillion is. Oh really, I just thought it's because I specified 4 and not because it's running on different processors (logical ones).

Comment: Do you have any idea where I can get my local host name to run resource managers on? I keep using the default one but it doesn't recognize it (it causes the process to crash)

Answer (score 0):

Some small points about mpirun or mpiexec commands:

If you are trying to run you app on multiple nodes, make sure that your app is copied to all the nodes.In addition, make sure that all needed binary files (executable & libraries) could be found directly from command line. I personally, prefer to run my MPI programs within a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/path/to/all/executable/files \
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/all/libraries \
mpirun -np 4 ./my_app  arg1 arg2 arg3
```